# How to split an inset from another inset

Tags: edit-mode

[image: The insets I want to split]

I want to split the insets so they are both no longer attached to each other but I have no clue how, I am attempting to make character legs.

Comment: Select single face at a time!

Answer (score 3):

if you hit "I" twice, it will inset individual faces. It's in the modal description:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the faces then choose: Mesh>>Extrude>>Extrude Individual Faces.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the inset tool you can select to Inset Individual Faces.

[image]